# Javascript clock with Images

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, date

I am pulling my hair out: my Javascript clock is not working. I am using Firebug to look for errors but I am not getting any output.

The image files are in subfolders `Dual_Months` and `Dual_Numbers`. I have added `document.write();` in my functions to see if they are firing but I am not getting any response. If anyone sees any obvious errors I would appreciate your help.

```
var imageclock=new Object()
imageclock.digits=["num_0.png", "num_1.png", "num_2.png", "num_3.png", "num_4.png", "num_5.png", "num_6.png", "num_7.png", "num_8.png", "num_9.png", "am.png", "pm.png", "colon.png"]
imageclock.months=["dual_jan.png", "dual_feb.png", "dual_mar.png", "dual_apr.png", "dual_may.png", "dual_jun.png", "dual_jul.png", "dual_aug.png", "dual_sept.png", "dual_oct.png", "dual_nov.png", "dual_dec.png"]
imageclock.instances=0
var preloadimages=[]
var preloadmonths=[]
for (var i=0; i<imageclock.months.length; i++){ //preload images
  preloadmonths[i]=new Image()
  preloadmonths[i].src="Dual_Months"+imageclock.months[i]
}
for (var i=0; i<imageclock.digits.length; i++){ //preload images
  preloadimages[i]=new Image()
  preloadimages[i].src="Dual_Numbers"+imageclock.digits[i]
}
imageclock.imageHTML=function(timestring){
//return timestring (ie: 1:56:38) into string of images instead
  var sections=timestring.split("/")
  for (var i=0; i<sections.length; i++){
    if (sections[i] == sections[0])
      sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Months/'+imageclock.months[0]+'" />'
    else if(sections[i].length==1 && sections[i] == sections[1])
      sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[0]'" />'+'<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[parseInt(sections[i])]+'" />'
    else if(sections[i].length!=1 && sections[i] != sections[0])
      sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[parseInt(sections[i].charAt(0))]+'" />'+'<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[parseInt(sections[i].charAt(1))]+'" />'
  }
  return sections[0]+'<img src="single_nums/'+imageclock.digits[12]+'" />'+sections[1]+'<img src="single_nums/'+imageclock.digits[12]+'" />'+sections[2]
}
imageclock.display=function(){
  var clockinstance=this
  this.spanid="clockspan"+(imageclock.instances++)
  document.write('<span id="'+this.spanid+'"></span>')
  this.update()
  setInterval(function(){clockinstance.update()}, 1000)
}
imageclock.display.prototype.update=function(){
  var dateobj=new Date()
  var currentdate=dateobj.getMonth()+"/"+dateobj.getDay()
  document.write(currentdate)
  var currenttimeHTML=imageclock.imageHTML(currentdate)
  document.getElementById(this.spanid).innerHTML=currenttimeHTML
}
new imageclock.display();
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` to debug - you mentioned you have Firebug (and FF comes with built-in dev tools), so use `console.log()`. Your image pre-load code is missing the `/` after the source folder.

Comment: P.S. Here's a "working" version: http://jsfiddle.net/xLNEs/ (it doesn't actually work since I don't have your images, but the syntax errors have been corrected so at least it does _something..._

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn for the info on the console.log i do more php programming than anything so I do a lot of "echo".

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax errors in your script.

Missing a `'` at the end of this line:

```
sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Months/'+imageclock.months[0]+'" />

sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Months/'+imageclock.months[0]+'" />'
```

Missing a `+` in this line:

```
sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[0]'" />'+'<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[parseInt(sections[i])]+'" />'

sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[0]+'" />'+'<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[parseInt(sections[i])]+'" />'
```

Comment: Thanks I am already seeing improvements (no longer staring at a blank screen) +1

Comment: The syntax highlighter actually tells you about mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript got snytax error correct it first

```
        if (sections[i] == sections[0])

            sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Months/'+imageclock.months[0]+'" />'

        else if(sections[i].length==1 && sections[i] == sections[1])

        sections[i]='<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[0]+'" />'+'<img src="Dual_Numbers/'+imageclock.digits[parseInt(sections[i])]+'" />'

        else if(sections[i].length!=1 && sections[i] != sections[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with the syntax errors i am already seeing some progress. +1